# How can I find application using hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

My hard drive is being used all the time (I can hear it and the HD LED is flashing).

How can I find the application that is causing this disk access? Is there something like `top` which shows the HD usage for each application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `iotop` command,

Usage:

```
sudo iotop
```